# How to get path for image, selected from gallery or captured through camera

Tags: iphone, image, imageview

I am trying to get path for image, selected from gallery or captured through camera.
I have tried using following code

```
imageView.image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:png];
[webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);
```

but when i check through terminal "documents " folder found to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

imageView.image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];  

NSLog(@"localFilePath.%@",localFilePath);
```

If you still get it empty then try by checking if NSData is created properly

```
NSLog(@"webData.%@",webData);
```